# Uploading Images to Firebase through a React App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I created a photo gallery app using React. When I upload an Image in the App, it is storing two documents of the image in the firestore, containing exactly the same 'created At' and 'url', but under two difference IDs. I want it to store only 1 document. I am not able to understand why my code is running twice and uploading the image twice?
Uploading is done using 'useStorage' custom hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { projectStorage, projectFirestore, timestamp } from '../firebase/config'

const useStorage = (file) => {
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        // references
        const storageRef = projectStorage.ref(file.name)
        const collectionRef = projectFirestore.collection('images')

        // uploading the file to the reference
        storageRef.put(file).on(
            'state_changed',
            (snap) => {
                let percentage = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100
                setProgress(percentage)
            },
            (err) => {
                setError(err)
            },
            async () => {
                const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL()
                const createdAt = timestamp()
                await collectionRef.add({ url, createdAt })
                setUrl(url)
            }
        )
    }, [file])

    return { progress, url, error }
}

export default useStorage
```

'useFirestore' custom hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config'

const useFirestore = (collection) => {
    const [docs, setDocs] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        // return a function to un-subscribe from the collection
        const unsub = projectFirestore
            .collection(collection)
            .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
            .onSnapshot((snap) => {
                let documents = []
                snap.forEach((doc) => {
                    documents.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
                })
                setDocs(documents)
            })

        // clean-up function
        return () => unsub()
    }, [collection])

    return { docs }
}

export default useFirestore
```

[image: Firestore image][image: App Output Image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove Strict Mode in index.js file, that is causing upload of file 2 times.